# p5.js: Make a Gradient Stroke with beginShape()

Tags: vertex, p5.js, perlin-noise

The following code generates a single particle at a random position. The particle moves right, once it's completely off the screen, it appears left again.

The particle creates a nice trail. However, I'd like the trail to fade out.
I tried setting the stroke color `stroke(random(255))` while setting the vertexes, but it changes the color of the entire shape instead.

You will find the relevant lines at the comment
`// draw particle and history` (approx. line 76)

https://codepen.io/normanwink/project/editor/XJoRYa

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="framerate"></div>
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/0.5.14/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function setup() {
                frameRate(30);
                createCanvas(1000, 500, 'WEBGL');

                particle = new Particle();
            }

            function draw() {
                background(0);

                particle.update();
                particle.edges();
                particle.show();

                var output = '';
                output += floor(frameRate()) + 'fps';

                document.getElementById('framerate').innerHTML = output;
            }

            function Particle(mX = random(width), mY = random(height)) {
                this.pos = createVector(mX,mY);
                this.vel = createVector(8,0);
                this.acc = createVector(0,0);
                this.maxSpeed = 8;
                this.trail = 60; // how long to track history
                this.history = [];

                this.update = function() {
                    this.vel.add(this.acc);
                    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
                    this.pos.add(this.vel);
                    this.acc.mult(0);

                    this.history.push(this.pos.copy());

                    if (this.history.length > this.trail) {
                        this.history.splice(0,1);
                    }
                }

                this.show = function() {
                    stroke(255);
                    strokeWeight(5);

                    // draw particle and history
                    beginShape();
                    for (var i=0; i<this.history.length; i++) {
                        var pos = this.history[i];
                        // stroke(random(255))
                        curveVertex(pos.x, pos.y);
                    }
                    endShape();

                    noStroke();
                    fill(255);
                    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 10);

                }

                // if particle hits the edge
                this.edges = function() {
                    if (this.history[0].x > width && this.pos.x > width) {
                        this.pos.x = 0;
                        this.history = [];
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (this.history[0].x < 0 && this.pos.x < 0) {
                        this.pos.x = width;
                        this.history = [];
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (this.history[0].y > height && this.pos.y > height) {
                        this.pos.y = 0;
                        this.history = [];
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (this.history[0].y < 0 && this.pos.y < 0) {
                        this.pos.y = height;
                        this.history = [];
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, it requires minor physics and handling the particles collision with the edges to work, so this is the most reduced version of the code.
For those who are interested, here is a full example: https://codepen.io/normanwink/pen/jLdpez

Comment: What exactly is your question? Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's much easier for us to answer specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. Which bit of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: Well, I got to disappoint you. I am exactly asking how to make gradient strokes on vector shapes. Sorry, that was quite unclear. My bad.

Comment: I am voting to close this as too broad. But can't you just assign a color whenever you draw a vertex? Modify that color over time, and you'll get a gradient.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Unfortunately not, it changes the color of the entire shape.

Comment: Then a much better question would be to post a [mcve] (note that your code is very complex, which makes it hard to help you debug) of what you've tried, and ask why it's not working. "Here's a ton of code, how do I do this" is very hard to answer.

Comment: In your case, just a single hard-coded "trail" would be enough. Anything else just makes it hard to help you.

Comment: That's why I added the code down below. To show you where the magic happens. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll edit the question to make it easier. Give me a sec ;)

Comment: I appreciate that. Yeah, if we can just copy and paste a simple example instead of going through your whole project, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Now, a reduced version is available. I hope it helps a bit solving the issue :D

Comment: I've retracted my close vote and upvoted your question and I appreciate you trying to post a better example. But note that it's a lot easier if you try to get it down to a minimal example. See my answer for an example of how you might do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better luck if you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried along with a specific techincal question. Here's an example:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}
  
function draw(){
  background(220);

  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(84,  91);
  curveVertex(84,  91);
  curveVertex(68,  19);

  stroke(128);
  curveVertex(21,  17);

  stroke(0);
  curveVertex(32, 100);
  curveVertex(32, 100);
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
```

We might expect this to show a very basic gradient on a path. (Notice how much easier this is to think about than your whole project!) But if we run it, then we'll see that it only ever takes the last color, in this case black.

To get around this, we need to break your path down into multiple shapes. Here's the same path, split into multiple shapes so we can give each section of the path a different shape:

```js
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(200, 200);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(220);
 
  noFill();
 
 
  stroke(0);
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(84,  91);
  curveVertex(84,  91);
  curveVertex(68,  19);
  curveVertex(21,  17);
  endShape();
 
  stroke(128);
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(84,  91);
  curveVertex(68,  19);
  curveVertex(21,  17);
  curveVertex(32, 100);
  endShape();
 
  stroke(255);
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(68,  19);
  curveVertex(21,  17);
  curveVertex(32, 100);
  curveVertex(32, 100);
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
```

If we run that, we'll see that the path does indeed have different colors.

You'd need to do something very similar where you break your path down into multiple shapes. Then you'd just need to modify the color passed into the `stroke()` function to create your gradient.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think p5.js handles it differently when the vertexes are created inside a for()-loop.

Comment: @Norman No, it's not different. But you do have to organize them in groups of at least 4 calls to `curveVertex()` at a time.

Comment: Oh boy thanks for being so patient. I think this gave me the push in the right direction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Norman No problem. Thanks for improving your question. This was an interesting one- I would have expected it to work exactly how you expected it to!